Is Manusmriti implying that later scriptures like Bhagavad Gita are false?
https://www.hinduismfacts.org/hindu-scriptures-and-holy-books/manusmriti/chapter-xii/


All those (doctrines), differing from the (Veda), which spring up and (soon) perish, are worthless and false, because they are of modern date.


Since the Bhagavad Gita is later than the Veda and denigrates "the flowery language" of the Vedas and karma-kanda - would Manu smriti consider such scriptures to be false?

I think it means scriptures like Bible, Quran, avesta etc

In chhAndogya upanishad, Shwetaketu studies all the vedas, but he does not know brahman.

No. Manu Smriti is talking about doctrines and not books. Here the doctrines of non-Vedic systems like Buddhism is implied.
If Hindu scriptures criticize any particular portion of Hindu scripture then it will give specific reference and not mention doctrinal difference with the Vedas. Below is an example of criticism of Munis who have emphasized sons.


"If Hindu scriptures criticize any particular portion of Hindu scripture then it will give specific reference" - not always true.  Vishnuist sectarian "scripture" has whole hog vilifications of EVERYTHING to do with Siva, including his devotees. @Pradip Gangopadhyay
